# LibreOffice Calc - text in a cell ending with an underscore and by a number will be converted to a small number

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Calc, If you enter text in a Standard cell ending with an underscore followed by a number, then the text is converted in the following way: the underscore is removed and the number is set in a small font (subscript).

Exemple:

If I enter `TEST_1` in a cell and press Enter, then the content of the cell is replaced by `TEST₁`

How is it possible to cancel this behavior ?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with current LO Calc 5.2.2.2 on Win 10. Does this replacement happen indenpendent of the count of numbers after the subscript? E.g., is `TEST_111111111`  transformed into `TEST_₁₁₁₁₁₁₁₁₁`? If not, check your AutoCorrect options (Menu `Tools` -> `AutoCorrect Options`)

Comment: Thanks for directing me in the right direction. The offending rule is depending on the language that's why I did not find the problem with a quick google search.

Comment: Happy to hear that you found the solution! With langauge set to french, indeed this is the "default", reproducable behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

The autocorrect behavior depends on the language.

In my case the Autocorrect options (in menu `Tools`->`Autocorrect`) were set to French (France).

The autocorrect rules causing this problem were in the form
`.*_0` converted to `₀`

It is possible to delete these rules to avoid the problem.

Comment: I chose to disabled Autocorrect, but you can also change the language to English, for example.